# bash equivalent for os.walk?

Tags: python, linux, bash, python-2to3

I am using 2to3 to fix my script library, and it seems to be a command line thing, not a shell thing.

I want to do all files from /home/me/scripts downward, assuming they end in `.py`. Is there an easy way to do 2to3 -y filename for each file under my folder in the shell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's `find` command:

```
 find /home/me/scripts  -iname "*.py" -exec 2to3 {} \;
```

The `-exec` argument tell it to execute the command that follows after this argument, which is `2to3 {}` in this case. For each file found, `{}` is replaced by the name of that file.

Comment: `-exec 2to3 {} +` would be a bit more efficient; it runs `2to3` on as many files as possible at one time, rather than running it once per file.

Answer (score 4):

`bash` 4 provides a way of doing recursive globbing.

```sh
shopt -s globstar
2to3 /home/me/scripts/**/*.py
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but to get the same effect as the `-iname` option in the accepted answer it is also necessary to use `shopt -s nocaseglob`.

Comment: Based on the question alone, I didn't see any need to ignore case. But yes, `nocaseglob` would allow matching `*.PY` (and `*.pY` and `*.Py`) as well as `*.py`.

Comment: I didn't test yours, I accepted his answer since it worked and I already migrated the files to py3